# Get one choice from tuple in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

'''
views.py, This works...But my problem is, how can get_or_create from the NOTIFICATION and save in my db
'''

```
b, created = Notification.objects.get_or_create(
        user = self.request.user,

        )
    b.save()
```

'''
models.py
'''

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    NOTIFICATION = [
        ('This is a book', 'This is a book'),
        ('This is pen', 'This is pen'),
        ]
    notification = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=NOTIFICATION)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Are you asking how to reference one of the choices? `Notification.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, notification='This is a book')` but without writing out the string for notification?

Comment: Yes....but i want to get it from my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to achieve this is to use constants in your class as the values for your choices

```
class Book(models.Model):
    NOTIFICATION_BOOK = 'This is a book'
    NOTIFICATION_PEN = 'This is a pen'
    NOTIFICATION_CHOICES = [
        (NOTIFICATION_BOOK, 'This is a book'),
        (NOTIFICATION_PEN, 'This is pen'),
    ]
    notification = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=NOTIFICATION_CHOICES)
```

Then you use these constants from the class

```
Book.objects.get_or_create(
    user=self.request.user,
    notification=Book.NOTIFICATION_BOOK
)
```